# Extend Immutable.js types

Tags: immutable.js

I would like to extend functionality of Map class. For example, I want to do following:

```
const someMap = Immutable.Map({ a: 1, b: 2 });
const {a, b} = someMap.batchGet('a,' 'b');
```

How can I correctly add 'batchGet' method to Map class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, core Immutable classes are not extendable by default. This was a design decision to discourage anti-patterns and to improve performance, see [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/301) for details.

That said, you can extend Immutable using [extendable-immutable](https://github.com/philpl/extendable-immutable), which philpl created in response to the above github issue. For you, that would look like:

```
import { Map } from 'extendable-immutable'

class MyMap extends Map {
  batchGet (...keys) {
    let result = {}
    keys.forEach(key => { result[key] = this.get(key) })
    return result
  }
}

const myMap = MyMap({ a: 1, b: 2 })
const {a, b} = myMap.batchGet('a', 'b')
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed